# Setting up Chebyshev interpolation

Tags: python, math, interpolation, polynomial-math

My h/w question asks me to "write a function that takes the limits of an interval and the order *n* of the polynomial interpolation *pn(x)*, and returns the data points *xi* that can be used for Chebyshev interpolation."

I have written the following function that produces a list of evenly distributed points *xi* on a given interval *[a, b]* to be used however I don't think I have incorporated the degree of my polynomial into this function, here *n* is just the number of points I decide to have, does this still answer the question?

```py
import numpy as np


def chebs(a, b, n):
    i = np.array(range(n))
    x = np.cos((2 * i + 1) * np.pi / (2 * n))
    return 0.5 * (b - a) * x + 0.5 * (b + a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your h/w questions refers to the [Chebyshev nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes) (the roots of the [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)), then yes, your Python function exactly answers the question. And yes, you have incorporated the order of the Chebyshev polynomial: as the order is arbitrarily chosen (e.g. you can have a second ordered Chebyshev polynomial *p2(x)*, third order *p3(x)*, etc.), your function argument *n* in the calculation of Chebyshev nodes is the order of the polynomial.